# Select 2 columns from access database to crystal reports select expert parameter

Tags: syntax, parameters, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

i have a ms access database with a table called daily . This table has 2 date column declared as string data type, now i have created a crystal report , now on reports-> select expert -> i have chosen the field name daily.indate and the value as parameter it works fine

But i have to select two columns daily.indate and daily.outdate . These two column is declared as string datatype hence i am using "starts with" function on crystal report so i can get the data show on reports.

This is the formula i use to do this.

{daily.indate} startswith {?date}

now if i use {daily.indate} startswith {?date} and {daily.indate} startswith {?odate}

i get error, i am not able to figure out what the formula is,

i am using crystal report version 10. professional edition . (stand alone not from visual studio).

Edit!!

Thanks all of you! now i got the error resolved

i used {daily.indate} startswith {?date} or {daily.outdate} startswith {?date}

now report is showing the data as i required,

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error message. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand 1) why you're using strings to represent dates, and 2) why you are using `startswith` instead of checking equality.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @bernie actually i do all the computing on front end hence i just use the field datatype as string to store date + time with seconds . Thanks for your reply!.

Comment: Glad you solved the problem. Cheers and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
{daily.indate} >={?date} and {daily.indate} <={?odate}
```

If you provide the error that will help in providing you more accurate solution.

Comment: @downvoter care to comment with proper reason, why voted down

Comment: i am sorry i don't know who down voted you! but this doesn't work because i use string data type to store date!. Thanks siva –

Comment: so datatype in database is string? If yes then create a string parameter for date and provide string as input in either case my answer will work...I suggest to give a try

Comment: Sure will try today Thanks Siva